# Создание таблиц для БД с кинофильмами

Tags: sql, база-данных

Мне необходимо чтобы в БД каждый фильм(таблица Movie) был связан с одним или несколькими актёрами(таблица Actor).

То есть я хочу чтобы в таблице с фильмами в поле актёры был список актёров, но при этом я хочу создать отдельную таблицу с актёрами(Actor), чтобы она ссылалась на таблицу Movie.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Это  связь M:N, которая требует отдельной связующей таблицы. *хочу чтобы в таблице с фильмами в поле актёры был список актёров* Крайне неудачное решение, чреватое проблемами при обработке.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как тогда сделать правильно?

Comment: Sheridan дал правильный ответ. Правда, он не показал PK/FK - добавьте сами (прочитав что-нибудь по теории отношения много-ко-много).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приблизительно как то так:

```
movies (id, name, ...)
actors (id, name, surname, ...)
movies_actors (movie_id, actor_id)

select movies.name, actors.name, actors.surname 
from movies
left join movies_actors on movies.id = movies_actors.movie_id
left join actors on actor.id = movies_actors.actor_id
```